# Align Fifteen Child DIVs as Bullets to Bottom of its Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I am editing in bullets of a slider. I want to apply gradient background on parent div of bullets so I need to increase height of parent div but when I am increasing the height all bullets are aligning on top of parent div.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
height: 200px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgb(27, 4, 4));
width: 100%; 
text-align: center;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
}
.child {
background-color: blue;
width: 25px;
height: 5px;
margin-left: 2px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Please let me know how to align all bullets on bottom of parent div.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1b2fuyvm/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox and you can easily align them:

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgb(27, 4, 4));
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end; /*put them at the bottom*/
  justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working but bullets are going to hide showing on responsive in my project.

Comment: add `flex-wrap:wrap` to the parent container

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're looking for, but if you want those lines to be at the bottom of the parent div, you could create another container div, set its position to absolute and bottom to 0. You will also need to find a solution to align it horizontally, such as setting the container width to 100%.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    ...
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1b2fuyvm/27/